# How do I save an image into a mongoDB collection using Kmongo?

Tags: mongodb, ktor, kmongo

I searched a lot today but all answers seem to be only in nodejs. I'm currently working on ktor application and I can't seem to find any way to upload images into MongoDB with KMongo.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) to store and retrieve binary files in MongoDB. Here is an example of storing an image, that is requested with the `multipart/form-data` method, in a `test` database:

```
import com.mongodb.client.gridfs.GridFSBuckets
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.http.content.*
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.litote.kmongo.KMongo

fun main() {
    val client = KMongo.createClient()
    val database = client.getDatabase("test")
    val bucket = GridFSBuckets.create(database, "fs_file")

    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        routing {
            post("/image") {
                val multipartData = call.receiveMultipart()

                multipartData.forEachPart { part ->
                    if (part is PartData.FileItem) {
                        val fileName = part.originalFileName as String
                        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            bucket.uploadFromStream(fileName, part.streamProvider())
                        }

                        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start()
}
```

To make a request run the following curl command: `curl -v -F image.jpg=@/path/to/image.jpg http://localhost:8080/image`

To inspect stored files run `db.fs_file.files.find()` in the mongo shell.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the exact same thing as your code shows in order to get the point of uploading an image file, but the problem is that the IDE does not resolve the function called uploadFromStream. Is that a custom function you have in your code or should I use uploadFromPublisher instead?

Comment: I found out that it is a function in GridFSBucket Interface. However, maybe it's something with the driver version of mongoDB?

Comment: In addition, I'm using coroutine version of Kmongo.

Comment: I use the `org.litote.kmongo:kmongo:4.3.0` dependency in Gradle.`uploadFromStream` is not my function but one from the `com.mongodb.client.gridfs` package.