# How to use GRIDFSBuckets with KMongo coroutine client

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, gridfs, ktor, kmongo

I am trying to use GRIDFSBuckets in ktor to upload files. I am using KMongo coroutine extension to create my MongoDB client. When calling GRIDFSBucket.create(). Its parameters need a MongoDatabase and bucketName. This is fine but KMongo coroutines creates a `CoroutineDatabase` not a MongoDatabase that is needed. Is there anyway around this?

[image]

Comment: Here you can find an example code to store a binary file https://stackoverflow.com/a/69162729/13963150. It probably works only with `org.litote.kmongo:kmongo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `MongoDatabase` instance from `CoroutineDatabase` by calling `CoroutineDatabase.database`. In your case that would be `db.database`